# how to save emails from outlook 365 to hard drive?

Tags: osx, outlook

Can I download my Outlook 365 emails to my hard drive for offline access?

Comment: You want software to do so? Please say so, otherwise the question may be off-topic here. And I assume it must synchronize two-way? What are you wiling to pay? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example.

Comment: yeah I did have the application but I had not known that it works for Office 365 as well. I thought it works for Mail app and Outlook2013/16 only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Outlook 365 emails can be downloaded to local folders by exporting the mail folders. 
However, this has a demerit as the emails are often not fully downloaded and thus are incomplete. Backing them up turns out to be worthless as the mails are hollow inside.

You can try out a third-party application like Mail Backup X. This tool backs up emails and warns against the emails that are partly downloading thus letting you download them forcibly. This can be claimed as the easiest way to save emails from Outlook 365 to Hard Drive.
linking the product for quicker search:http://www.mailbackupx.com/how-to-scenerios/how-to-backup-outlook-mac-mails-on-mac.html

Comment: Thanks Stella. that helped. The mails were archived to complete offline copies. good tool indeed. 
Thanks.